# Find a resource both in .jar and eclipse with the same String computation

Tags: java, resources, path, javax.imageio

I want to get the path to a resource for ImageIO to read out a BufferedImage from some .png s.
While developing the project I use a relative path to "/bin/stuff/icons/image.png" , but this will definetly not work when I put everything together into a .jar file, so I need a way to get the path to these resources both while testing in eclipse and when later running it within a .jar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trying out both finding the file and getting the input stream to the file I came to the conclusion that this approach works every time:

```
InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in)
```

Where path is

```
"projectName/resourceFolder/" + nameOfResource.stuff
```

as found in the src directory of the eclipse project.

E.g.

```
"myProject/images/icon.png"
```

When getting only the resource and then getting the path of the resource to link to a file, you will get FileNotFoundExceptions when using a .jar (but not while testing with eclipse, so one should be warned to think that his code works).

And - no - I don't save images in the bin/ - but they are copied to this directory and thus I find them there while testing. Now everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put anything under the `bin` directory in Eclipse: if you run a clean on the project it will be erased.

What you can do is to define a new source folder like `resources`, and put the image there. This way it will be automatically copied to the `bin` folder.

If you include the `resources` folder into the Jar, it will be available in both environments by using something like:

```
ImageIO.read( getClass().getResource("/image.png") )
```

PS: You can evade using a different resources folder but mixing the sources and images will quickly pollute your source folder.